# Lambda error: ExpressionAttributeValues must not be empty when using API Gateway

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Using the test in the lambda function, the update method succesfully inserts the data in the correspondent column of the database. However when I try it in API Gateway as a PUT request triggering this lamdba function, the following error appears:

> Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: ExpressionAttributeNames must not be empty

Here´s the code of the function:

```js
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    // manually id:
    let scanningParameters = {
        Key: {
            "email": event.email
        },
        UpdateExpression: "set sites = :sites",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
         ":sites":event.sites
        },
        TableName: 'Users'
    }

     return docClient
    .update(scanningParameters)
    .promise()
    .then(() => {
        return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        'headers': { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }})
    
   
}
```

I have tried changing `ExpressionAttributeValues` by `ExpressionAttributeNames` but it hasn´t worked either.

Answer (score 0):

When you use API gateway for lambda proxy integration, recommended way, the `event` object send to your function has special [format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format):

```
{
    "resource": "Resource path",
    "path": "Path parameter",
    "httpMethod": "Incoming request's method name"
    "headers": {String containing incoming request headers}
    "multiValueHeaders": {List of strings containing incoming request headers}
    "queryStringParameters": {query string parameters }
    "multiValueQueryStringParameters": {List of query string parameters}
    "pathParameters":  {path parameters}
    "stageVariables": {Applicable stage variables}
    "requestContext": {Request context, including authorizer-returned key-value pairs}
    "body": "A JSON string of the request payload."
    "isBase64Encoded": "A boolean flag to indicate if the applicable request payload is Base64-encode"
}
```

Comment: I´ve seen that format several times looking in the API too but I have no idea where I´m supposed to send that. Should I send it in the request?